# :checked pseudo class selector is not working on CSS

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I am trying to show/hide a image using :checked pseudo class using only css.
The console shows no error but I am not able to see the image on clicking the checkbox.

HTML Code :

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="java.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="div1"></div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="chk1">
        <img src="IMAG0182.jpg" style="display :none"></img>

    </body>
</html>
```

CSS Code :

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked + img {
display : block;
}
```

Comment: Why is your question tagged with javascript and jQuery if you're asking a pure css question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inline styles will always override a stylesheet,it's one of the rules of [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Set the initial state in the stylesheet

```css
input[type=checkbox] + img {
  display: none;
}


input[type=checkbox]:checked + img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="chk1">
<img src="IMAG0182.jpg" />
```

Comment: Still not working now the image is always showing irrespective of the checkbox checked or unchecked

Comment: Well, the demo in the answer seems to work perfectly fine, so I don't really now what the problem is? Maybe you have some other styles that are interferring ?

Comment: Still not working, only this part is working alone input[type=checkbox]:checked{}