# Check box doesn't open up menu when toggled

Tags: html, sass, responsive-design, navbar, hamburger-menu

I am making a responsive navbar which turns into the hamburger icon on mobile phones. I used media queries to check for mobile phones and create a hamburger icon. Then I made a mobile menu which appears and disappears when the hamburger icon gets toggled. Here is my code:

### HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Responsive Nav Bar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- Nav Bar -->
    <nav>
      <h2>Nav Bar</h2>
      <div class="nav-left">
        <a>Home</a>
        <a>About</a>
        <a>Blog</a>
        <a>Contact</a>
      </div>
      <div class="nav-right">
        <a>Log In</a>
        <a>Sign Up</a>
      </div>

      <div class="mobile-nav">
        <label for="toggle"><h2>&#9776;</h2></label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
      </div>
      <div class="menu"> <!-- Mobile Menu -->
        <a>Home</a>
        <a>About</a>
        <a>Blog</a>
        <a>Contact</a>
        <hr>
        <a>Log In</button>
        <a>Sign Up</button>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

### SASS (Use Compiler):

```
// Fonts
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Mukta&display=swap");


* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

// Navbar
nav {
  width: auto;
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;

  h2 {
    color: #303030;
    font-family: "Mukta", sans-serif;
    margin-right: 30px;
  }
}

.nav-right {
  margin-left: auto;

  a {
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-top: auto;
    font-family: "Mukta", sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(109, 109, 109);
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
  }

  a:hover {
    color: #26b1db;
  }
}

.nav-left {
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;

  a {
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-top: auto;
    font-family: "Mukta", sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(109, 109, 109);
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
  }

  a:hover {
    color: #26b1db;
  }
}

div.mobile-nav {
  display: none;

  label {
    display: none;
  }

  #toggle {
    display: none;
  }
}

.menu {     // Mobile Menu Styling, Display is none
  width: 100vw;
  font-family: "Mukta", sans-serif;
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  z-index: 1000;

  a {
    margin: 5px 0px;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
  }

  a:hover {
    color: #26b1db;
  }

  hr {
    margin: 5px 0px;
    border-color: #a3a3a3;
    border-style: solid;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  div.mobile-nav {
    width: auto;
    height: 60px;
    display: flex;

    label {
      display: block;
      cursor: pointer;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-top: auto;
      margin-bottom: auto;
    }

    #toggle:checked + .menu {  // Displaying the Menu
      display: flex;
    }
  }

  nav h2 {
    font-size: 5vw;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }

  div.nav-left {
    display: none;
  }

  div.nav-right {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

The problem is in this line:

```
#toggle:checked + .menu {
  display: flex;
}
```

When clicked on the hamburger icon, it doesn't display the menu, instead it keeps it's display to block.

### Things I have tried:

1. Changing the display to block when the the toggle checkbox gets clicked
2. Setting display to none for unchecked and flex when checked as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45132916/checked-pseudo-class-selector-is-not-working-on-css)
3. Putting .menu div and #toggle checkbox in a single div as Toni Michel Caubet said (This method does work, thanks but it works with a single element like an h1, not with a div containing many elements)
4. Changing the combinator or grouping .menu div and #toggle checkbox after putting them in a div

### EDIT:

At point 4, things started to work a bit. When I changed the + to a comma to group both of them, the menu appeared. But it didn't closed after clicking it again. I changed the display to block of the hamburger menu, and the checkbox was checked when the page got loaded. But after unchecking it, **the checkbox disappeared but the menu didn't**. I need a solution to this.

#### NOTE:

I want to make this entirely in CSS (Or SASS) without the use of JavaScript or jQuery

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your problem is that `.menu` is not in same container than the checkbox. so `:checked + menu` doesn't apply to menu (discard the label). you have to place the input in same level than the menu right before. `+` operator works with the immediate sibling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Few things going on here.**

- As stated in the comments, the problem is that your checkbox isn't in the same container as your mobile nav.
- You also have some `<a>` tag, closing as `</button>`, meaning that your html is incorrect.

### Solution

- Keep the label of the checkbox where it is.
- Move the checkbox to be a direct sibling of `.menu`.
  Then adjust your css to have `#toggle` as a selector and not `div.mobile-nav #toggle`.
  `toggle` is an id, you don't need to have a stronger specificity as it's a unique element.

**Short reminder of the selector:** `.foo + .foo2`
This selector will select every element with the class `.foo2` if they are the next sibling of a element with the class `.foo`.
Therefore, they have to be in the same parent node and be one next to each other.

```
<nav>
  <h2>Nav Bar</h2>
  <div class="nav-left">
    <a>Home</a>
    <a>About</a>
    <a>Blog</a>
    <a>Contact</a>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-right">
    <a>Log In</a>
    <a>Sign Up</a>
  </div>

  <div class="mobile-nav">
    <label for="toggle"><h2>&#9776;</h2></label>
  </div>

  <-- I've moved the checkbox. Now the selector #toggle + .menu will work  -->
  <input type="checkbox" id="toggle"> 

  <div class="menu"> <!-- Mobile Menu -->
    <a>Home</a>
    <a>About</a>
    <a>Blog</a>
    <a>Contact</a>
    <hr>
    <a>Log In</button>
    <a>Sign Up</button>
  </div>
</nav>
```

---

```
// Fonts
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Mukta&display=swap");


* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

// Navbar
nav {
  width: auto;
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;

  h2 {
    color: #303030;
    font-family: "Mukta", sans-serif;
    margin-right: 30px;
  }
}

.nav-right {
  margin-left: auto;

  a {
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-top: auto;
    font-family: "Mukta", sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(109, 109, 109);
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
  }

  a:hover {
    color: #26b1db;
  }
}

.nav-left {
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;

  a {
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-top: auto;
    font-family: "Mukta", sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(109, 109, 109);
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
  }

  a:hover {
    color: #26b1db;
  }
}

div.mobile-nav {
  display: none;

  label {
    display: none;
  }

}
#toggle {
  display: none;
}

.menu {     // Mobile Menu Styling, Display is none
  width: 100vw;
  font-family: "Mukta", sans-serif;
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  z-index: 1000;

  a {
    margin: 5px 0px;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
  }

  a:hover {
    color: #26b1db;
  }

  hr {
    margin: 5px 0px;
    border-color: #a3a3a3;
    border-style: solid;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  div.mobile-nav {
    width: auto;
    height: 60px;
    display: flex;

    label {
      display: block;
      cursor: pointer;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-top: auto;
      margin-bottom: auto;
    }


  }
  #toggle { //#toggle is on it's own now, it doesn't need more specificity
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
  }
  #toggle:checked + .menu {  // Displaying the Menu
    display: flex;
  }
  nav h2 {
    font-size: 5vw;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }

  div.nav-left {
    display: none;
  }

  div.nav-right {
    display: none;
  }
}
```